# How to reload the D3 svg element after setting the state of the dataset in REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, codepen

Hi guys i'm playing with D3.js and React trying to create a dancing bargraph, how do i reload the D3 svg after setting the state of the dataset in REACT? here's my

```
codepen: https://codepen.io/mav1283/pen/LJwWVw?editors=0010
```

Nevermind the state display on top, it's a temporary debugging section.

Answer (score 1):

First problem is **loadBarGraph** should be a callback after the **setState** is done.

Elements appended to the "enter" selection are no longer automatically added to the main (update) selection. You now need to explicitly create a **merge** selection, by calling the merge method on the "enter" selection:

```
    const rect = this.svg.selectAll('rect').data(dataset);
    rect.exit().remove();
    rect.enter()
        .append('rect')
        .merge(rect)
        .attr('width', 25)
        .attr('height', (d, i) => {
            console.log(d);
            return 3 * d;
        })
        .attr('x', (d, i) => i * 30)
        .attr('y', (d, i) => h - d)
        .attr('fill', 'green');
```

New Code pen : https://codepen.io/imsontosh/pen/yRBXKg?editors=0010

Comment: Thank you so much!